# Theorem 2.5-5 from the Introductory functional Analysis by Erwin Kreyszig

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

I don't understand why $X_1$ has dimension *one*? (underlined in the text).
Also, Riesz's 
lemma says that $x_2$ must belong to a set of which $X_1$ is a proper subset of it; how it can be a proper subset if both has the property of their norms being equal (=1)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_1$ is the span of the single vector $x_1$ so has basis $\{ x_1 \}$ and hence is one dimensional.

Edit: To answer the second question that you added - $X_1$ is a closed proper subspace of $X$ since $\mbox{dim}(X) = \infty$ so we are able to apply Riesz' lemma to the subspace $X_1$ of $X$ to find a vector $x_2 \not \in X_1$ with the desired distance property. Note that $X_1$ contains exactly one vector of norm $1$ whilst $X$ contains infinitely many.

Comment: So not all elements of $X_1$ has norm 1?

Comment: No. No subspace can contain only elements of norm 1.

Comment: But how $X_1$ can be a *proper* subset of another set which has an element of norm 1?! (second question in OP)

Comment: @Edi see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $X_2=span\{x_1,x_2\}=\{ax_1+bx_2|a,b \in \mathbb{F}\}$

and $X_1=span\{x_1\}=\{cx_1|c \in \mathbb{F}\}$

Now $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ because evey evely element of $X_1$ is has the form $ax_1+0x_2 \in X_2$ where $a,0 \in \mathbb{F}$

Also note that in a normed vector  space $X$ it is possible to find elements $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $||x_1||=||x_2||$ but this does not always imply that $x_1=x_2$

Take for instance $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual norm $||.||_2$

and $x_1=(1,0,0)$ and $x_2=(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ which are also linearly independent.

We have that $||x_1||_2=||x_2||_2=1$ but $x_1 \neq x_2$  and $$A=span\{x_1\} \subsetneq B=span\{x_1,x_2\}$$